# Plot a long Stop Loss ONLY if a "Go Long" position is active

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I'm getting to grips with the basics of Pine Script Version 5.

Basically, I'm looking to plot a Stop Loss on the chart, but ONLY if a long position (moving average crossover) is open and active.

The Stop Loss itself is the longer Exponential Moving Average minus 2 x average true range.

Any help would be massively appreciated, and thank you in advance
Here's the simple coding I've done so far (and I know that it's a simple tweak that is needed):

```
    //@version=5
    strategy("EMA Crossover", overlay=true, margin_long=100, margin_short=100)

    //Indicators
    SEMA = ta.ema(close, 24)
    LEMA = ta.ema(close, 48)
    STOP = ta.atr(24)

    //Plot them
    plot(SEMA,"SEMA", color.black)
    plot(LEMA,"LEMA",color.blue)
    plot(LEMA+STOP, "Short Stop", color.red)
    plot(LEMA-STOP, "Long Stop", color.green)

    //Enter long
    longCondition = ta.crossover(SEMA,LEMA)
    if (longCondition)
        strategy.entry("Go Long", strategy.long)

    //Enter short
    shortCondition = ta.crossunder(SEMA,LEMA)
    if (shortCondition)
        strategy.entry("Go Short", strategy.short)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `strategy.position_size` built-in variable to figure out your market position.

> Direction and size of the current market position. If the value is >
> 0, the market position is long. If the value is < 0, the market
> position is short. The absolute value is the number of
> contracts/shares/lots/units in trade (position size).

```
is_long = strategy.position_size > 0
is_short = strategy.position_size < 0
is_not_in_position = strategy.position_size == 0
```

Comment: Thanks for this (as I'm going to master position sizing next), but do you know the answer to my question?  Do you mean use this variable to only plot a stop loss on the chart during an open long position? Thanks.

Comment: This is the answer to your question. That variable tells you if you have an open long/short position at the moment.

Comment: Brilliant. But do you know what I would type in to link it to only plotting a line on the chart if there's a long position open? (Something like "if  is_long plot (ta.ema)" ) I'm still really new to this! Thanks again.

Comment: You can use those variables in the `series` argument of your `plot()`. So, something like this `plot(is_long ? ema_valur : na)`. This will only plot the ema value if you are in a long position.

Comment: Hi Vitruvius, I've experimented with the code I'll paste below.  The idea is to only plot a stop level when the short EMA has crossed over the long EMA.  However, it doesn't work!  The error message says ........... Mismatched input ',' expecting ':'       What do you think is needed?

Comment: plot(SEMA > LEMA ? LEMA-STOP, "Long Stop", color.green : na)